# How can I extract tables from PDF documents with Python?

Tags: python, pypdf, summary

[the report pdf like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILYld.png)

And  I want to read the information in it and convert into a class  or another object

[this is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYJKl.png)

```
def GetUrl(self):
    auth = qiniu.Auth(self.__access_key, self.__secret_key)
    base_url = "84320875399.pdf"  
    private_url = auth.private_download_url(base_url)

    return private_url
 
def DownloadPdf(self,url:str):

    response = requests.get(url)
    pdf_data = response.content

    return pdf_data
 
def TryParsePdf(self,data):

    pdf_file = io.BytesIO(data)
    pdf_reader = PdfReader(pdf_file)

    for page in pdf_reader.pages:
        # print(page.extract_text())

        text=page.extract_text(0)
        rows = text.split('\n')
        for row in rows:
            print(row)

def PrasePdf(self):
    url=self.GetUrl()
    
    data=self.DownloadPdf(url)

    if self.TryParseDef(data):
       print("success")
```

If `pypdf2` does not implement this function, please tell me what library can I choose

Help me!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: pypdf2 is deprecated. Use pypdf.

Comment: Also your script is not complete (.e.g imports are missing). It likely also is not minimal. Besides that, functions in Python should be `snake_case` not `PascalCase`

Comment: It's unclear to me where the issue is: (1) Downloading a file (2) Reading the contents of a PDF file (3) object orientation in Python (4) something else. Please focus on one of them.

Comment: The script  is just  a  demo ,because i  dont know  how to prase pdf.  I want to get the   table's  elements  and  convet to k-v object. But i have no idea how to do it

Comment: page.extract_text()  this  method  can get all text  of the report,but  is  irregular. do you have some advice  to make the test regular

Comment: So your question is "How can I extract tables from PDF documents with Python"?

Comment: yeah,  this is  Amazon Summary Report